# Raycasting center of camera is not working: why?

Tags: unity, raycasting

In my game i'm using Unity First Person controller. 
I check every second what I am looking with the following code:

```
 cam = Camera.main;
 RaycastHit hit;
 Vector3 CameraCenter = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, cam.nearClipPlane));
 if (Physics.Raycast(CameraCenter, transform.forward, out hit, 5))
 {
      WhatIamLookinTag = hit.transform.tag;
 }
```

The problem is that isn't working if move Up and down player "view" (so i move up and down mouse..)

I need the object that is in screen center (based on what am i looking).

Why ?

Comment: I notice you're getting the position of the camera from one object (`cam`), and the direction to fire the ray from what might be another (`this.transform`) - are these the same object in your example? Can you show us how you've populated the `cam` variable?

Comment: You were right, like all times you help me. Many thanks man !

Comment: If you've solved your problem, feel free to post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem: cam.transform.forward instead transform.forward

```
cam = Camera.main;
 RaycastHit hit;
 Vector3 CameraCenter = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, cam.nearClipPlane));
 if (Physics.Raycast(CameraCenter, cam.transform.forward, out hit, 5))
 {
      WhatIamLookinTag = hit.transform.tag;
 }
```

Thanks to DMGregory.